# Enable Dialogflow ES TTS agent setting programmatically

Tags: dialogflow-es

Are there any way to enable Dialog flow ES agent TTS setting via java code(or event other language)?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJYEa.png)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to "enable" the agent TTS. It is just a matter of setting on your intent detection call the audio output settings.

You can see an example on the `request json body` sample at this page: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/detect-intent-tts#detect_intent

Comment: hi Luciano, in my case I don't use any fulfillment and just have static intents programmatically restored for my created agent. As I understand your given  example case I need to have some java code deployed in cloud and enabled fulfilment for it, right?

Comment: Hi Diana - actually, no. To use the static responses configured into your intents, and still have audio (TTS) responses, you just need to do the API call to detect intent API and request the audio output. You'll only use fulfillments if you want Dialogflow checkin for a intent response externally (ie. making one API call request against another API and deliver the API response as the user feedback).

Comment: Luciano, are you saying that I don't need to enable fulfillment and have my code (detect intent API )deployed in google cloud ? Could you guide where will be my code running and how configure agent to use my code(which will do DetectIntent for each request)?

Comment: Hi Diana! There is [this pathway](https://developers.google.com/learn/pathways/chatbots-dialogflow) that may guide you through the process of creating a simple chatbot. I think it might clarify things for you

Comment: Luciano, now I see what you mean, but I don't control user's requests to my dialogflow agent, I only control just building agent configuration part.